# How to scrape data from newly opening webpage?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-automation

To scrape data from webpage which is opening after clicking a *submit* button

In [this website](http://www.omnilogistics.com/) I'm filling textbox showing place-holder **#Tracking** with this value **148459** after filling clicking *Submit* it opens another page, with details... I want to scrape the data on that page and bring it into Excel using VBA.

My guess is that the *Submit* button is using POST method; I need help to scrape the webpage with POST method.

I've worked out with below code:

```
Dim IE    As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc     As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput   As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButton  As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim txt As String
Dim delStat As String

txt = ActiveCell.Value
IE.Visible = True
'IE.Navigate "http://206.50.6.194/WebtrakWT/shipinquiry/quicktrack.aspx"
IE.Navigate "http://206.50.6.194/WebtrakWT/shipinquiry/ShipInfo.aspx?OrderNo=393874&Back=QuickTrack&TrackType=HousebillNo&TrackNo=" & txt
Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

'Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlTrackBy")
'HTMLInput.Value = "HousebillNo"
'Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtInputNo")
'HTMLInput.Value = ActiveCell.Value
'Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'    DoEvents
'    Loop
'Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnSubmit")
'HTMLButton.Click

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop

Set HTMLAs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")

For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs
    Debug.Print HTMLA.getAttribute("id"), HTMLA.innerHTML
Next HTMLA

delStat = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lblStatus").innerHTML
Debug.Print delStat

If delStat = "DELIVERED" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Delivered"
Call screenShot
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Not Delivered"
End If

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you have any code which you've tried to help you scrape from the webpage?  As SO is designed to help with coding, not code for you, it would help the process along.

Comment: Hi cyril.. I"ve use Below code